# List all events of all logs

Tags: powershell, event-log

I am pretty new to PowerShell and would like to find a way of listing all events from all logs. My idea is to index each event in Elasticsearch and perform queries on them. I am particularly interested in each event detail:

- Message
- process ID
- Parent Image
- ...

I know there are command to list the logs and events of a particular log file. I was curious to know if a guru has a short and sweet solution while I continue finding my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-3.0):

> ### Get-WinEvent
>
> Module: `Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics`
>
> Gets events from event logs and event tracing log files on local and remote computers.
>
> […]
>
> **`-LogName`**
>   Gets events from the specified event logs. Enter the event log names in a comma-separated list. ***Wildcards are permitted.*** You can also pipe log names to Get-WinEvent.

Emphasis mine. [Related](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/03/07/use-powershell-to-query-all-event-logs-for-recent-events/).